# Enforceable array structure in PHP using ArrayObject?

Tags: php, arrays, arrayobject

I've a set of data (~30 properties, all having their own array of values) that I want to pass around to various classes in PHP and I want to also enforce the data's array structure. Multiple classes will be expecting this structure to be consistent.

Because of these facts I can't really rely on a standard array and so I decided to pass an object around. I looked into ArrayObject and while it allows me to set/get as if the class were an array I didn't see anything about enforcing the structure.

Is there an existing standard class that can handle enforcement of it's array-like structure while still being treated as an array, e.g., basically ArrayObject + enforcement?

An example of the array structure:

```
$item_type_props = array(
    'phone'     => array('speed' => 1000, 'self_label' => false, 'support_poe' => true, 'bluetooth' => false),
    'pbx'       => array('acd_support' => true, 'max_conn' => 300, max_phones => 600),
    'adapter'   => array('fxo' => 4, 'fxs' => 0, 't1_e1_pri' => 0),
    etc...
);
```

I know each property in the array could be it's own class and enforce it's own fields through the constructor and set/get but then I suddenly have ~30 classes that are nothing but a bunch of attributes and that seems somewhat excessive for just holding data.

---

Alternatively, if I'm just approaching this from the wrong mindset and missing something really, really obvious then please do point it out.  I get the feeling that I am but my brain might be having a vacation.

Comment: Classes may not be that much of an overkill if you'll end up making ~30 validation definitions. In the end it would be the same as creating ~30 classes but you'll also be working against PHP instead of with it.

Comment: @apokryfos, sorry could you clarify "working against PHP" for me?

Comment: PHP will enforce the rules governing the classes you define for you because it does allow OOP syntax. If  you write classes then the PHP language will be helpful but if you go with ArrayObjects you're undoubtably going to end up hitting a few limitations along the way because (in my opinion) the ArrayObject is a bit hacky to begin with. If you want a middle ground maybe implement a few self-validating structures.

Comment: Of course it would help to examine where the data is coming from as well. If it's from an API then there's a chance there's a service descriptor for that API somewhere so you can just use that to auto-generate classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you could roll your own, I encourage you to use an existing validation implementation. For example, [`Symfony\Validator`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/raw_values.html) allows you to define nested structures and the requirements on each level:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
    // the keys correspond to the keys in the input array
    'name' => new Assert\Collection(array(
      'first_name' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 101)),
      'last_name' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 1)),
    )),
    'email' => new Assert\Email(),
    'simple' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 102)),
    'gender' => new Assert\Choice(array(3, 4)),
    'file' => new Assert\File(),
    'password' => new Assert\Length(array('min' => 60)),
));

$violations = $validator->validate($input, $constraint);
```

This lets you push the details of *how* to validate down to another (already tested) level, while letting your code focus on *why* it needs this data. For the Symfony case, you can use an `array` as the storage mechanism, and use a design that firewalls unvalidated from validated data.

---

One way we might do this is notationally. Pretend we have implemented a method, perhaps using Symfony's validator, to return a validated array. We can use Hungarian notation to indicate our structure has passed through validation and is "safe":

```
<?php
$vInput = validate($_GET); // Hungarian notation: any variable beginning with "v" is "validated" and safe to use

function foobar(array $vInput) { ... }
```

While this is performant, it's not great for maintenance in the long term. So, you might consider an object wrapper that allows you to leverage the type system:

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class ValidatedArray extends \ArrayObject {
    public function construct($input = [], $flags = 0, $iterator_class = 'ArrayIterator') {
        $violations = Validation::createValidator()->validate($array, $this->constraints());
        // throw exception if any violations
        parent::__construct($input, $flags, $iterator_class);
    }

    public function __offsetSet($index, $value) {
        $constraints = $this->constraints()[$index]; // specific constraints to this index
        $violations = Validation::createValidator()->validate($array, $constraints);
        // throw exception on violations
        parent::__offsetSet($index, $value);
    }

    public function constraints() {
        return new Assert\Collection(...);
    }
}

$input = new ValidatedArray($_REQUEST); // first time validation
$input['foo'] = 'bar'; // also subject to validation
```

You might want to make this implementation an `abstract` base class, with concrete descendants implementing the `constraints` method to provide the specific limitations on the array object itself. This provides a flexible way to get dedicated Data Transfer Objects.

Comment: Yep, I was stuck on the wrong approach.  I kept thinking "enforce" when "validate" would have led my thoughts to the right location.  @bishop are you suggesting a class (extending ArrayObject) and a validate method that the consuming classes can call which in turns tells them the data they are reading is fully structured (true/false with malformed error)?

Comment: That is one approach. Hungarian notation is another. There are lots of ways to go about it, though. The "best" way really depends upon your existing code base. Edited some ideas into answer.

Comment: In the end I've combined both of your @gaidinaman answers (sort of).  I made a Collection class extending ArrayObject with validator to check that the collection has the required keys.  I made value objects for the item_types in the collections and use Ocramius's Hydrator to quickly populate those.  I use a loop to hydrate and add each hydrated item to the collection.

Comment: Bishop, the `$constraints = $this->constraints()[$index];` that you mentioned is not valid.  Did you mean `$constraints = $this->constraints()['fields'][$index];`?

Comment: That sounds about right. I did not compile or test, just approximated the requisite code.

Comment: Darn it.  Well, I'm having trouble finding a way to extract a index's rules.  I'll spend some time digging through Symfony's API & code as well as look at other packages to see if they have an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

Generally speaking I would argue that - unless you are passing data to another context, e.g. javascript - a PHP application should be nicely organized in PHP classes. This is simply the easiest way to enforce the structure. Your are right, this might result in quite straightforward DTO's with a bunch of getters and setters, but it will beat checking array structures for sure. In your case there also appears to be a relationship in the array, otherwise it would not make sense combining them into an array at all.

Using PHP7 you can clearly define the method signature and enforce the types, e.g.

```
public function setSomething(string $myValue)
{
    $this->something = $myValue;
}
```

Same with return types:

```
public function myActionMethod(array $options): ActionRespsonse
{
    // Do something
}
```

If you have more complex data types, I would recommend using Value Objects. These are nothing more but simple PHP classes that represent a more complex value. For example, a phone number:

```
public function setPhoneNumber(PhoneNumber $phoneNumber)
{
    $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
}
```

Here the PhoneNumber is a Value Object which effectively is a tiny class by itself which enforces its usage:

```
class PhoneNumber {
    private $phoneNumber;

    public __construct(string $phoneNumber) {
        if (strlen($phoneNumber) != 10) {
            throw new \Exception('Not a valid phone number');
        }

        $this->phoneNumber = $phoneNumber;
     }
}
```

This is also where the validation can tie into the answer from @bishop as you can use an existing Validator to help you out. You can find an example of a Value Object of a Phone Number here (just googled it): [Example Phone Number Value Object](https://github.com/Antnee/PHP-Value-Objects/blob/master/src/PhoneNumber.php)

I do have the feeling that you might be converting your PHP data to an array for another reason? Like interacting with a database, or passing it on to a different context, such as Javascript?

In that case, once you have your DTO's and VO's neatly defined you can then consider serializing them e.g. to/from JSON. You can use Symfony libraries for that, as described here: [Symfony Serializer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

If you really want arrays you can also consider hydrating them to/from entities, using the library from Marco Pivetta (ocramius) who is pretty much the authority on hydration an approach extensively used in Doctrine: [Ocramius Hydrator](https://github.com/Ocramius/GeneratedHydrator)

Plenty of options, eh!?

To be honest, though, IMHO typically there would need to be a pretty good argument to pass these complex arrays around as arrays offer very little in supporting functionality. In addition, your code will very likely and very quickly become difficult to read and maintain, as at every point where there would be some kind of modification of the array, or usage of its data elements, you would need to implement all kinds of checks or run a validation as described by @bishop. I would not allow something like that to exist in our applications code bases...

So, concluding: If you have a tightly defined set of PHP Objects with well established constructor, properties, getters, setters, constructor, relationships, action methods and besides that some kind of serializing mechanism, you're in good shape. Also other developers will be 'forced' to work with the objects and provided interface (methods and VO's) thus guaranteeing a degree of maintainability and quality.

By the way, you might consider reasing Martin Fowler's thoughts about these things: [Martin Fowler: DTO](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html) [Martin Fowler: VO](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) [Martin Fowler: DTO2](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html)

Comment: Thoughtful answer. Appreciated. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks @bishop, to be honest, it's about time I start contributing back to the community... I'm a big fan of 'clean code' concepts and as such stick myself to a pretty rigid development practice which I also teach to my team. I would recommend this book if you are interested: https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882

Comment: I am in fact passing the data around. In the DB it is stored in a 4 column table of id, item_type, item_prop, and value.  The data structure in DB vs. PHP is different.  I had considered $a->getPhone()->hasBluetooth(), but the whole setting / getting from $_POST to class is what led to looking at ArrayObject.

Comment: I thought you might be doing that, it is a common challenge when developing applications that interact with databases or API's. Now if this is just a small project and you're the only maintainer, I would say do whatever works for you. But if it is anything else, I would always choose to decouple 'db stuff' from 'application stuff' and not let challenges from one domain cause you problems in another. In other words: get your data from the database and transform it in a PHP object that 'makes sense', i.e. decouple/interface

Comment: ... and as an after-thought: just consider that if you do NOT decouple, then a database change might propagate through your entire code base... if you DO decouple, then you would have to change the mapping from the database to the object, but the object itself would remain unchanged...

Comment: @gaidinaman When you say value object are you envisioning 1 for each item type and that each VO validates itself?  Or is the VO just a container for the various properties (1 VO per item type) which one day may have behaviors?  Regarding why this complex array...  well I have a series of Q&A responses from customers that are fed into a class containing rules for the a solution. The item property data is used by the rules to produce a response (a collection of items) that fits their criteria, i.e., it builds a rough draft of the phone system.

Comment: @PatrickSJ Yes, the concept of a Value Object would entail that you create one for each 'kind' of item. For example, if you have three URL's being passed, you can create one 'URL' Value Object (PHP Object) with one constructor that receive e.g. a string. The Value Object itself can be reused three times, however, in this example. Our code bases have kind of 'common' libraries for these Value Objects that are re-used throughout projects.